# Can't make Ken Burns effect zoom properly

Tags: video-editor, final-cut-pro-x

I'm trying to use the Ken Burns effect in FCP X. I have no problem accessing the functionality and altering the settings, but when I run it in the preview, the video just shows as zoomed in and then pans across. I have it setup to do a zoom in and pan. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use keyframes for both the pan and the zoom changes?